# default system proxy settings

Tags: c#

I'm going to sent SOAP-request to the host via proxy. I use two variants: manual proxy settings and system proxy settings. There is my code:

```
        if (UseProxy.Equals("manual"))
        {
            WebProxy p = new WebProxy(pServer, true)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUser, ProxyPass)
            };

            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p;
            Request.Proxy = p;
            Request.Timeout = 10000;
        }
        else if(UseProxy.Equals("system"))
        {
            IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Request.Proxy = proxy;
            Request.Timeout = 10000;
        }
```

Manual settings are working well, but system proxy settings don't work at all. I can not send anything and program hangs out on request regardless of the timeout parameter.
Also I tried the following:

```
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyHost, 8080);
            proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            Request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
            Request.Proxy = proxy;
            Request.Timeout = 10000;
```

It didn't work too. Please explain me where is my error? Class with SOAP-requests was generated authomatically using wsdl-file.

Comment: re: using the system proxy - what happens if you don't change the request's default proxy?

Comment: @arootbeer the same as in case of "system" parameter

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Sorry

Comment: Have you tried using `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` instead of DefaultCredentials (in the original setup).

Comment: @Me.Name with DefaultNetworkCredentials the same situation...

Comment: And the user under which the application runs, has full internet access? What happens when you open the URL in IE in the user account?

Comment: @Me.Name in ie all is worhking, current user has admin rights

Comment: Perhaps silly of me to ask, but you are sure the `else if` condition is satisfied and the proxy is being set? Just making sure ;)

Comment: @Me.Name according to log system condition is satisfied